# To Print no of copies and specific page, get input from msgbox

Tags: excel, vba

In vba I want to print documents

To print N th page and N no. of cpoies, as per the input given by user.

I want to get inputs using msg box.

Thanks in advance.....!

Comment: Do you have any code already?

Comment: For this particular part i dont have

Answer (score 0):

You should use [PrintOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838253%28v=office.15%29.aspx) method and [InputBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468%28v=office.15%29.aspx) (type:1).